# Is it a REST web service?

Tags: web-services, rest, apache-axis

I am working on a legacy application which have a `.war` with following structure (and I want to add my `servlet` in this war)

```
     myApp.war
      - axis2-web (Downloaded from http://ws.apache.org/axis2/download/1_1/download.cgi)
      - META-INF
        -- MANIFEST.MF
      - WEB-INF
        -- classes (But it don't have any `.class` file , it have `log4j.properties` file)  
        -- conf (Contains `axis2.xml`)
        -- lib (contains many jars)
        -- modules 
        -- services (Some `.aar` files)   
        -- web.xml
```

Here is the `web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <display-name>Apache-Axis2</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
        <!--<init-param>-->
        <!--<param-name>axis2.xml.path</param-name>-->
        <!--<param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/axis2.xml</param-value>-->
        <!--<param-name>axis2.xml.url</param-name>-->
        <!--<param-value>http://localhot/myrepo/axis2.xml</param-value>-->
        <!--<param-name>axis2.repository.path</param-name>-->
        <!--<param-value>/WEB-INF</param-value>-->
        <!--<param-name>axis2.repository.url</param-name>-->
        <!--<param-value>http://localhot/myrepo</param-value>-->
        <!--</init-param>-->
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AxisRESTServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet (REST)</display-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRESTServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>Apache-Axis AxisAdmin Servlet (REST)</display-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisRESTServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/axis2-admin/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>/axis2-web/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
      <error-code>404</error-code>
      <location>/axis2-web/Error/error404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/axis2-web/Error/error500.jsp</location>
    </error-page>


</web-app>
```

Is it a REST web service ? I Googled and found some tutorials on [REST](http://wso2.org/library/3726) which says REST services have `services.xml` file but I couldn't find it in my application. I want to integrate my `servlet` in above war so what will be the right way to do it ?

**PS:** Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: REST is an API design style, not a specific technology or implementation. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: @skaffman: Sorry for this nonsense question. Could you please provide me any pointer so that I can google things and get some idea to integrate my servlet in above code.

Comment: @Ajinkya: The tutorial you link seems to have the principles right if you carefully read the introduction. Also have you tried the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST)?

Comment: @Jan:Will check it again. What about services.xml ? Should it be there or not ?

Comment: @Ajinkya: I don't actually know Axis2, but think it's independent question from whether it's RESTful or not, because RESTful property of the interface design, not particular way of implementing it.

Comment: @Jan : Okay. Will try to make more concepts clear and then will try for answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand RESTFUL WS approach that the it has a traditional http request and response with get ,post ,put or delete operations directly passed to the web service  and so the response doesn't have any special format (JSON-RPC,SOAP) .
For example , if we write simple code some-service.jsp and put this code on our server 
the restful tells us to call the service using any http client passing it the required params 
and then we will get the service response .
Now if your application meets this , it would be RESTful  .

Note : there are no any specific implementation techniques for REST it is just a WS approach

hope this would help you

Comment: Thanks for the information.What wil be the good way to integrate my servlet in above war ?

Comment: you can alter the war file to put your servlet in classes firectory and then redeploy the war file

Comment: I tried adding my servlet and updating `web.xml` but it didnt work.

Comment: I mean unpack app.war , add serlet then update xml and then repack it

Comment: Thanks. Will try again and let you know.